# Removing categories, Comments etc from posts?

Tags: categories, themes, comments, editor

im wondering if there is a way to completely remove this feature from my website as i have no need to categorise any of my posts - i plan to post projects in pages from my left sidebar with a static front page. I am really new to this and read that i may need to edit the theme (Editor is my current one, though there's nothing there yet so willing to change if there is a theme with an easier way to do it) I am not at all familiar with coding and went to the editor page to have a look after reading a way to remove categories, comments etc, but would have NO idea at all where to type the changes. I removed author, comments, tags, comments and dates from the screen options on my posts page but it still appears on my (currently test) first post. As i say i'm just getting started, am very novice at this and want to make sure things will look as i want them to before i start making pages and posts.

Thanks so much for any help :)

Answer (score 0):

There are probably several approaches to doing this. One approach would be to select the categories and comments divs in your theme and use css to remove them.

Example: In your style.css

```
.entry-utility-prep-cat-links {
    display:none;
}
```